# Adding old FID to new feature class using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, objectid

I have been tasked to relocate some assets, about 1000 preexisting point and line feature classes.  I will be collecting the correct GPS coordinates to realign all the assets but I'm not sure how to link the new coordinates to the old feature class FID.

I am new to GIS and I'm using ArcMap 10.6.

Comment: You shouldn't use FID values for *anything*.  They exist so that the data can function. You should always use your own unique ID for any project which requires tracking the evolution of features. You can copy from the FID value to start, but from there out you need to maintain the value yourself.

Comment: @Vince you should add that as an answer, because that's the answer.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. The organization has set up the FID attribute as a unique ID for every single asset within the company. 
To move the feature classes to the correct location, would it be a manual process of inputting xy coordinates?

Comment: Are you relocating _feature classes_ - which are database tables in their entirety - or the _features_ representing various assets?

Comment: I'm hoping you're referring to file geodatabase objectids, and not shapefile FID values, since it's not possible to coordinate FID values across shapefiles. So, in addition to clarifying if you have 1000 feature classes or 1000 features, please specify the format of the data.

Comment: This is called replace geometry and it is doable without creating new feature class because field Shape is editable like most other fields. Yep, with points if is no more than typing correct xy into 2 fields. Use arcpy.Point(!xfield!,!yfield!) in calculator to move all points in one go. It is slightly more complicated with lines